# firestore verifyId token

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-admin

With firestore admin SDK,we can verify the firebase ID token using the method

> verifyIdToken()

The purpose of this function is to verify the ID token explicitly,if i am correct

why should we verify the ID token explicitly?.Because it will done by firestore security rule automatically while making the request if the rule is like this

> match /databases/{database}/documents {

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid!=null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore admin sdk can be used with your server application and to authenticate request to your application you can use  `verifyIdToken`.
This would not be required if your client is directly connecting with firestore.

Comment: so if i am making a sensitive operation i don't want to explicitly verify idToken,right?it will be done by firebase itself?

Comment: if your server application is directly communicating with firestore, your server application is authorized using service key so the security rule does not apply.

Comment: Yeah i know,so while making an http request,like callable function https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable we can verify the token using this function,right?

Comment: @pepe yes you can call the verify function.